# Is switch-case over enumeration bad practice?

Tags: dependencies, design, enum

I have an enumeration with the commands `Play`, `Stop` and `Pause` for a media player. In two classes I do a switch-case over the received commands. The player runs in a different thread and I deliver the commands in a command queue to the thread.

If I generate class diagrams the enumeration has dependencies all over the place. Is there a nicer way to deal with the commands? If I would change/extend the enumeration, I would have to change several classes. (Its not super important to keep the player extensible, but I try to write nice software.)

Comment: I just want to make a comment that though @MainMa's answer makes sense in this situation, using an enum in a swtich statement in general is not bad practice and can make your code much more readable. It's just a case of getting a feel for when it's appropriate. public enums should probably be saved for things like configuration values of a class, etc.

Comment: @TZHX - in some cases, sure, they make sense.  In general though, switch statements are an abused flow control mechanism; often, they indicate a single method where there should have been multiple.  As with this case, there really isn't any reason to squeeze these 3 methods into one, and things often get fun quickly with different parameters for the various cases in the switch.  I would recommend only using them when you want to unify multiple methods for some reason - e.g. having a single validate method for a form, which then delegates out, based on state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "nicer" way is to have three methods, one per command.

There is no need to collapse all those commands into one method and to use a switch later. Since those commands do different things, they deserve their own methods in the interface.

Instead of:

```
public void ChangeState(PlayerState newState)
{
    switch (newState)
    {
        case PlayerState.Play:
            // Start playing.

        case PlayerState.Stop:
            // Stop playing.

        case PlayerState.Pause:
            // Pause or resume.
    }
}
```

you would have:

```
public void Play()
{
    // Start playing.
}

public void Stop()
{
    // Stop playing.
}

public void Pause()
{
    // Pause or resume.
}
```

Why?

Your current implementation using a switch will:

- either do multiple things,
- or will just serve to call `Play`, `Stop` and `Pause` methods.

In the first case, you break the rule which says that **a method should do one and one only thing**.

In the second case, **KISS**: don't write a method you really don't need and which doesn't bring anything useful to the API.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing is taking 3 separate inputs, merging them into a single variable, and passing that along to be processed.  Your processing code then does a switch / if statements on this variable.

As MainMa mentioned, the obvious and cleaner approach would be to simply have 3 methods, and have your interface call those.  If, for some reason, you wish to have a slightly more disconnected model (say, if you need to execute the command at a later stage then when it's triggered), the typical way is the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) where you effectively encapsulate a method call in an object (which can be serialised / stored / sent over the network / run multiple times, etc).  The advantage over your enum is that it caters for input parameters (e.g. if you have a volume control command).  That said, this is an unneccessary over-complication, and I'd stick to plain old methods.

Comment: I would like to use the different methods, but I have to call them somehow in the new thread. Would the command pattern be justified in this case? (As far as I know, I should not call methods on runnables from the main thread)

Comment: @Puckl In terms of not calling methods from the main thread, it really depends on whether they are long-running operations, or not - if it's likely that the operation will be too quick for the user to notice, running it in a background thread is generally just complicating the code.  Aside from that, it depends on how you intend to handle the different threads.  If you have a worker thread that processes incoming requests, the command pattern can work, and may be justified.  In C#, however (I'm guessing your language), there are easier ways to make async calls.

Comment: The Command Pattern is basically a workaround for OOP languages that lack first-class functions and/or closures. In a sufficiently equipped language, one can just pass the relevant command functions directly. In C#, I'd say delegates are the way to go.

Comment: @tdammers Yepp, delegates / closures for C# would be best.  Re: command, the "workaround" definition only really holds if you only use it for that, in which case I agree.  I'm yet to see a language give first-class support for the things I normally do with Commands, like serialising them for replayability / audit trails, etc.  I'm not sure I *want* a language which goes that far.

Comment: @DanielB: Good point on the replay etc.; I don't think it's relevant here, since you won't get those features with switch/enum either.